# Iteratively reading specific elements within an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to read specific elements within lines of an ArrayList. For example, an array list called Combinations of size 3 with the following lines is being produced by my code:

```
Combinations =

[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 2]
```

I would like to create a loop that will read each line of the array, each element of that line, and add strings to a new array depending on the values of that array line. What should I use in order to accomplish the following pseudocode in java?

Pseudocode would be as follows

```
For (int i = 0; i < Combinations.size(); i++)
   If Combinations(Line i, First Element) = "0" 
   Then NewArray(i).add("Vial1,")
   If Combinations(Line i, First Element) = "1"
   Then NewArray(i).add("Vial2,")
   If Combinations(Line i, First Element) = "2"
   Then NewArray(i).add("Vial3,")

   If Combinations(Line i, Second Element)= "0"
   Then NewArray(i).add(+"Vial1")
   If Combinations(Line i, Second Element)= "1"
   Then NewArray(i).add(+"Vial2")
   If Combinations(Line i, Second Element)= "2"
   Then NewArray(i).add(+"Vial3")
```

The resulting ArrayList would then be:

```
NewArray = 

[Vial1,Vial2]
[Vial1,Vial3]
[Vial2,Vial3]
```

Below is the code which I am using to generate my Arraylist

```
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.CombinatoricsUtils;

public class Combinations1 {

public static void main (String[] args){
ArrayList<Integer[]> combinations = new ArrayList();
Iterator<int[]> iter = CombinatoricsUtils.combinationsIterator(3, 2);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    int[] resultint = iter.next();
    Integer[] resultInteger = new Integer[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        resultInteger[i] = Integer.valueOf(resultint[i]);
    }
    combinations.add(resultInteger);
}
for (int i = 0; i < combinations.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(combinations.get(i)));
}}}
```

Comment: and you question is what exactly?

Comment: maybe use an enum instead of an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudocode is a bit of a mess. You seem to be wanting to turn what is currently an array of Integers into an array of Strings.

I think you want something like this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> NewArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (Integer[] combination : combinations) {
    String[] newCombination = new String[2];
    if (combination[0].intValue() == 0) {
       newCombination[0] = "Vial1";
    }
    ... etc for other possible values
    if (combination[1].intValue() == 0) {
       newCombination[1] = "Vial1";
    }
    .. etc for other values
    NewArray.add(newCombination);
}
```

Of course if your rule is exactly 0 -> Vial1, 1 -> Vial2 etc, you don't need to handle each case separately, but instead:

```
newCombination[0] = "Vial" + (combination[0].intValue() + 1);
```

and the same for the second element. If the rule is the same for both you could just iterate over the elements of the array too. Hopefully you can figure that out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
String[][] newArray = new String[combinations.size()][2];
for (int i = 0; i < combinations.size(); i++) {

Integer[] eachArray = combinations.get(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < eachArray.length; j++){
        int elem = eachArray[j]; 
        if (elem==0 || elem==1 || elem==2){
            newArray[i][j]="Vial"+(elem+1);
        }
    }
```

}